# ¿Como decrementar un numero hasta 0 usando un bucle for?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo bucles para decrementar el valor de un numero elegido por el usuario hasta 0, la cosa es que no se como hacerlo con bucle for ya que no soy capaz de hacer que pueda decrementarlo mas allá del numero 10

el código es el siguiente:

```
var introduce = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un numero "));
for (let introduce = 10; introduce >= 0; introduce--) {
    
    document.write(introduce);
}
```

Comment: Usa la variable que declaraste como parámetro de tu for. Quedaría: `for (let introduce = 10; introduce >= 0; introduce--){ document.write(introduce); }`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, ya lo había probado y sigue sin funcionarme pero gracia igualmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pruebalo así:

```js
var introduce = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un numero "));

for (introduce; introduce >= 0; introduce--) {
  introduce - 1;
  console.log(introduce);
}
```

Comment: estas seteando el valor a 10, esta mal, asi no importa que ingresas.

Comment: @kkk Esta respuesta es la correcta según entiendo, o esto no es lo que buscas?

Comment: @Emeeus pues no me funciona quizá debería pasar el código entero ya que este código va dentro de un switch pero en teoría no debería haber problema con ello ya que los otros dos bucles me funcionan, lo que quiero hacer es poner por ejemplo 300 y que me cuente de 300 a 0, osea 300-299-298, hasta 0, y lo quiero hacer con el for pero soy incapaz de hacerlo funcionar

Comment: No debería haber problema en un switch, fijate que aqui puso `console.log(introduce)` en lugar de `document.write(introduce)` osea que lo vas a ver en la consola, no en la pantalla.

Comment: @kkk hace lo que pides, si lo quieres ver en la pantalla cambia el `console.log(introduce);` por `document.write(introduce);` y te hará lo que buscas...

Comment: @valle50, pues si es verdad, no se como lo he probado antes pero no me funcionaba, muchas gracias